# Add Oracle Spatial Vector Layer with QGIS 2.0 on Mac OSx

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I installed version 2.0 using the recommended mac installer (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis), and the installation went fine, but there is no option to add an oracle spatial layer (not in the layer dropdown, or the sidebar buttons). I assume this has to do with gdal configuration, but I'm not sure how to fix that. I have the oracle instant client installed, and I can connect to oracle with sqlplus. Has anyone been able to get the new support for oracle to work on a Mac?

Comment: It's been three years, and still no support for oracle in the linux or mac versions, very disappointing

Comment: Now it's been 7 years, and QGIS for mac comes with an official installer, maybe it has Oracle support? I don't personally use oracle anymore, just postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, the distributor of the binary for mac osx, replied again, and basically said that one would need to compile QGIS manually. Here are the instructions he posted:

> You'll have to compile QGIS yourself...
>
> You need OCI Basic (or Basic Lite) and OCI SDK.
>
> unzip the sdk
>
> unzip basic
>
> rename the clntsh dylib to remove the numbers at the end (should end
>   with .dylib).  you can ignore the occi dylib since it's not used. 
>   copy libclntsh and libnnz11 to /usr/local/lib
>
> update clntsh with:   install_name_tool -id
>   /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib -change
>   /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib
>   /usr/local/lib/libnnz11.dylib /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib
>
> add to QGIS cmake configure before the last ".." (make sure to fill in
>   correct path to your OCI sdk):
>
> -D WITH_ORACLE=true -D OCI_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib \
>   -D OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/unzipped/oci/sdk/include \
>
> "Oh, look, I seem to have fallen down a deep, dark hole.  Now what does that  >remind
>   me of?  Ah, yes - life."
>
> Marvin

Comment: unless someelse has more detailed instructions, or has actually done this on their own, I'm going to just accept this answer for now

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build QGIS 2.8 myself using mock but the issue with Oracle connection is still there.
See this: http://courses.neteler.org/compiling-qgis-2-0-1-for-fedora-19-in-a-few-steps/

You can try using cx_Oracle via python or adding oracle spatial layers via odbc.
By the way I have set this on a Virtual Linux Red Hat 7.
Please let me know if you made it work.

Comment: I never got it to work :(
This is the only impediment for adoption of qgis at my organization

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that it isn't supported as kingchaos stopped supported it. My answer is based on a conversation from QGIS mailing list and you can understand everything from:

```
On Tue, Oct 22, 2013 at 8:00 PM, William Kyngesburye
kyngchaos wrote:

> Now I remember another reason(s) why I stopped supporting Oracle (in
> GDAL)...
>
> Attitude - registration I can deal with, but requiring full business
> contact info is too much.
>
> They STILL don't know how to name OS X libraries.  As is, cmake will not
> find them.  Neither will standard configure scripts (ie GDAL).  This means
> renaming the libraries (and fixing the internal linking) and organizing the
> libraries and headers to build for them.  But while end-users could do the
> same library renaming without much fuss, the internal link fixing requires
> a tool from Xcode, which defeats the point of installing prebuilt binaries.
>
> I don't really want to deal with this. :(
>
> On Oct 22, 2013, at 9:25 AM, chris marx wrote:
>
> > Ok, Thanks for the heads up. I've been using the Oracle instant client
> as well as Oracle Sql Developer with no problems on my mac. I think the OCI
> libraries come with the instant client?
> >
> > http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html
> >
> >
> > On Tue, Oct 22, 2013 at 10:18 AM, William Kyngesburye <
> kyngchaos> wrote:
> > I figured someone else would have a good answer.  I wasn't aware of the
> new Oracle driver, and when you mentioned it I thought it was
> self-contained or used GDAL.
> >
> > But now that I look at it closer, I did not build QGIS with Oracle
> support (it's direct support, not thru GDAL).  I gave up on the OCI
> libraries for OSX a long time ago, but maybe they've caught up recently.
>  I'll look into it.  There's nothing you can do to get the existing build
> to work.
```

Comment: hi, yeah, that's the conversation I had with him on the mailing list. I don't think that qualifies for the bounty. If anyone can post information about how to attack the build on our own, that would be welcome