# How to compile QGIS with Oracle Spatial support for Linux?

Tags: qgis, ogr, oracle-spatial

I compiled it on Fedora and Ubuntu, but got error "Cannot get Oracle select dialog from provider." while trying to add Oracle layer.
Packages in repositories don`t have oracle spatial support.
Can somebody help me?
I need deb or rpm package with oracle spatial and qgis-mapserver support.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: possible answer here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74842/add-oracle-spatial-vector-layer-with-qgis-2-0-on-mac-osx. It's for OSX but going by description it might apply to linux as well (need to download the Oracle SDK seperately).

Comment: I use Ubuntu and Fedora. I compiled qgis with this manual but adding oracle layer not working: "cannot get oracle select dialog from provider"